# Apollo client queries and data store when connected to multiple components

Tags: javascript, react-native, graphql, apollo-client

I have 3 different components that use the same graphql query.  This example would be `GET_USERS` query.  This is used when looking for users to message in the messaging respective tab and also when inviting users for actions and tagging them when creating posts.

the problem I'm having and trying to figure out how to handle is that its not always the case that only one is rendered at a time.  A user might click the message tab and then go to tag a user in the post tab.  **Problem**:  when he comes back to the message tab it now has re-rendered with the state of the query that was called from the tagging.

Any suggestions on how to set up the state with Apollo and the queries in general to avoid this issue.  At the end of the day my backend is one "route" or `resolve` function for the specific action.

**EDIT**
For further information.  The way I know I could solve it is to use axios request to the graphql endpoint and store the response in local `useState` for that component.  If I did this for each of the different places in the app that use the information they would remain decoupled and not share the exact same state.

But to be clear I am trying to solve this while using Apollo if possible.

Comment: simply use `cache-only` fetchPolicy in queries/components you want to not affect 'main source of truth' ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a combination of local state (useState) and [useLazyQuery](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#executing-queries-manually).
From what I understand you have multiple components (or screens, tabs, whatever) mounted at the same time, say ScreenA and ScreenB. In each of them you query GET_USERS, but when your query results update in ScreenB, you don't want to also update the results in ScreenA.

With useLazyQuery this could look like this:

1. Create a custom hook for easy reusability across components

```
export const useLazyGetUsers = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState()

  const [queryGetUsers] = useLazyQuery(GET_USERS, {
    onCompleted: (data) => setUsers(data.users),
    onError: (error) => console.log('onError', { error }), // handle errors as you wish
    fetchPolicy: "cache-and-network", // or whatever you want
  })

  return {queryGetUsers, users}
}
```

2. In ScreenA, use the hook and fetch the query:

```
const ScreenA = () => {
  const {queryGetUsers, users} = useLazyGetUsers()
  
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => queryGetUsers()}>
      <Text>Get users</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
```

3. In ScreenB, also use the hook.

Note that you can call `queryGetUsers` whenever you want, on mount, on TouchableOpacity press, or whenever.

```
const ScreenB = () => {
  const {queryGetUsers, users} = useLazyGetUsers()
  
  useEffect(() => {
    queryGetUsers()
  }, [])

  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

4. Use `users` as you wish. If you call `queryGetUsers` in ScreenA, it will not update the value of `users` in ScreenB.

This is not a 100% Apollo solution but it makes minimal use of local state and the hooks makes it very easy to reuse. I hope this solves your issue!

You can read more about `useLazyQuery` here:

- https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#executing-queries-manually
- https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#uselazyquery

Comment: Do you know how to resolve the same issue when we have not separated but the map of the same reusable component? screens.map(screen => < ScreenA />)

Comment: @Julia not sure what you are talking about. Maybe post a question with more details and tag it here, then I can take a look.